# open source instant messenger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, instant-messaging

I am using VSTS 2008 + ASP.Net + Forms Authentication + .Net 3.5 + IIS 7.0 + C# to develop a Web Application. I want to add web based instant messenging feature to my web application (using Forms authentication), I just need very basic features, like text based message, user presence status, etc.

I want to know whether any ready-to-use and easy to integrate components? Better open source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jabber/XMPP is open-source, there are many implementations (client and server) that are mostly open source. Just check out [XMPP Standards Foundation](http://xmpp.org/).

By the way, You'll find a list with implementations of web-based clients [here](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml#web).

Also, there's a mono/.NET-implementation, called [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/).

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for my scenario for XMPP client and server?

Comment: I noticed many of them are Java/Linux based. I want to find .Net based server and client, which could utilize my existing skills. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like jabber-net is just a SDK (looks like no server?), what I want is a more ready to use server/client.

Comment: jabber-net is written in c# but it's mostly intended for client-side implementations. I actually don't know a jabber-server for .NET, but you might want to use ejabberd (http://www.ejabberd.im/) which is a server-implementation (not just) for windows (even though it's written in Erlang).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I do not know Erlang. :-(

Besides C#, I prefer Java. Any Java based easy to maintain Windows based server to use (appreciate if you could recommend me a related web based client)?

Comment: If Java is an option, try tigase (http://www.tigase.org/). It's a jabber-server, but they also develop a web-based client (http://www.tigase.org/en/project/messenger).

Comment: OpenFire is another free XMPP server written in Java. Very simple to configure.

Comment: If I use OpenFire, what do you think is the web based client?

Comment: Could you send files to other users with this solution?

Comment: Never tried that, but if I wanted to, I'd implement the file-transfer from client to host using http-post and notify the recipient with a link to download the file (of course, native xmpp would do this in a different way, but this looks like the way to go when devoloping a web-based PIM-system).