# Looking for library for Instant Messaging, like libpurple, but written in C#

Tags: c#, .net, instant-messaging

I'm looking for an Instant Messaging library that at minimum supports YM, MSN protocol - preferably free but if it's worth to pay, why not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**msnp-sharp** is the open source protocol written in c# for MSN. You can get it from http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/ . Its very active.

But i don have any experience with yahoo IM protocol. This link showed up in google search [YM Trainer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/YCC_Trainer.aspx). And Just give a try http://www.ycoderscookbook.com/, incase you are not aware of.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, have you had a look at [libpurple-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/libpurple-sharp/source/browse/#svn/trunk/LibPurple/LibPurple) which are .NET bindings for libpurple. Even if the project hasn't released a package, there is a lot of code there already and perhaps it is enough for your application.

I think that the only way that you will achieve support for as many protocols as libpurple is to either use libpurple or port it to .NET.

Comment: *...either use libpurple or port it to .NET.*  Yes, and porting it would not bbe so simple, I suspect.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of a multi-protocol IM library for .NET... there are separate implementations for almost all protocols, however. If you really need that, I suggest you create your own library ;).

I can see 2 main options for doing that :

- Create a .NET wrapper for libpurple
- Use the existing separate protocol implementations, extract an abstraction level that fits all of them, and put them all together.

I think the first approach is the best, because the abstraction level probably already exists in libpurple. Whichever you choose, it's going to be a lot of work anyway...

Comment: .NET Wrapper for libpurple:  http://code.google.com/p/libpurple-sharp .  See also, Michael Dillon's response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672201/library-for-instant-messaging-like-libpurple-but-written-in-c/1718239#1718239

Answer (score 0):

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538913/open-source-instant-messenger)

[Jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/): "A set of .Net controls for sending and receiving Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP), also known as the Jabber. "

Comment: libpurbple do a bit more them xmpp, like msn, aim etc ... so depend on what he wants to do

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do you can run Pidgin and "listen" to events with DBUS (nDBUS IIRC).

This will allow you to respond to events from Pidgin in .NET code (like the currently logged in user receives a message).