# Ultimate chat-client API for .NET?

Tags: .net, api, components, chat, pidgin

Does anyone know of a .NET API (source-code is preferrable of course) that I can access all the common chat clients thru it (GT, Yahoo, MSN, AIM, FB, ICQ, SKYPE and more)?

I guess I am looking for a .NET library project that performs something like pidjin.

I need it because I hate Pidgin's interface and functionality, and I want to have a Google-Talk desktop like UI.

Any comments and tips will also be very useful.
Thanks.

Comment: Pidgin is open-source...you could always check out the latest revision and port it to .NET ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672201/library-for-instant-messaging-like-libpurple-but-written-in-c).

There is a .NET port of libpurple [here](http://code.google.com/p/libpurple-sharp/), but it seems pretty much dead (last commit was more than 2 years ago...)

Comment: Do you know any project which is porting libpurple to .NET and active?

Comment: nope... the only project I found is the one mentioned in my answer