# open source instant messenger?

Tags: c#, open-source, instant-messaging

I am looking for an open source instant messenger based on .Net technologies (C# on Windows), and an open source project which has a small code base is appreciated, since I only need basic text message exchange function. Better authentication by a remote web services.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Maybe this may be of help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538913/open-source-instant-messenger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533578/any-open-source-instant-messenger Or maybe some of these links:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c%23/#/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XMPP Standards Foundation links to several .NET SDK libraries for those who wish to build their own IM.

Here's one link:
http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/

There's also a CodeProject link that shows how easily you can be up and running using agsXMPP:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/JabberClient.aspx

Hopefully you find these to be good reading!

Comment: there is one more: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

Comment: Good point. I should rephrase my answer!

Comment: This isn't open source

Comment: @Zimano: 5 years ago it was. Please don't expect me to go back to my posts from 5+ years ago and keep them up-to-date. That's bordering on the ridiculous...

Comment: @code4life I didn't expect you to; it's just a heads up for others reading the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is C#, SIP instant messenger:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/officesip/